# jQuery Mobile double popup for Google Maps contact us page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile-popup

**THE INTENT:**

> I have a single-template jQM page that I want to have list of the different stores we have.
>
> > **Here is a live example: http://bit.ly/WU7N1P**
>
> I want to have one reusable `DIV` container for the popup and then update the `src` of the nested `iframe` as users tap on one location or the another.  The base of my implementation is from the jQM Google Map plugin and I have added to it.
>
> I'm creating a parameter of the latitude and longitude of the location that gets tapped, then passing it in the `URL` to the `showMap.html` file which is the `iframe` `src` and where the Google Map is getting loaded in the iframe.  I've also added a marker to the map so users can see the exact location of the store.

---

**THE ISSUE:**

> When a user taps a button to open a map to it appears that there are two (2) popups that get loaded?  So when you close the map popup and second blank popup remains and it too needs to be closed.
>
> ***Note:** Most of the times you can recreate this issue on the first 'open map' button but may need to tap a second, different, 'open map' button to recreate the issue*
>
> I've been completely stuck on this for a couple of weeks and am hoping someone can shed some light on this issue for me.
>
> > **Here is a jsFiddle to work with as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/hmQZk/3/**

---

> Thank You very much in advance!
>
> WizzyBoom

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was in popupbeforeposition state and line:

```
    $('#popupMap iframe').attr('src', 'http://map.matchstickcrew.com/showMap.html?latlng=' + latlng);
```

I have removed it and put it inside a :

```
$('.btnShowMap').on('click', function() { 
    latlng = $(this).attr('data-latlng'); 
    $('#popupMap iframe').attr('src', 'http://map.matchstickcrew.com/showMap.html?latlng=' + latlng);
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/hmQZk/5/

But if you would like to listen my advise, you should abandon this iframe solution and switch to [gMap v3 api](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples). Basically you will get the same thing without using iframe as a proxy.

Comment: I've tried that before and I'm getting the same issue when I test it on Mobile Safari.  So I've taken your advice and setup a gMap v3 implementation, however I now have too issues.  1) I can't seem to get the zoom to be different.  I'm shooting for 'zoom' : 12.  2) When I tap the first 'Open Map' it shows up fine (though zoomed in), but when I tap on a different 'Open Map' it is not refreshing.  I have my script all in the <head> of the index.html file found here http://map.matchstickcrew.com/ (I couldn't get jsFiddle to work with the plugin and gMap API external script calls).  Any ideas?

Comment: I have a working example, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7kGdE/. Tell me if you need anything more. And what do you mean "When I tap on a different 'Open Map'"?

Comment: So what I mean about 'Open Map' is at http://map.matchstickcrew.com you'll see a list of Stores. Tap (click) 'Store 1' and then tap (click) the 'Open Map' button.  You'll see that Store 1 loads a marker somewhere in Annapolis (zoom out to see city).  Next tap (click) on Store 3 and then tap (click) that 'Open Map' button.  I should load a marker somewhere in the Boston area but instead it just loads the previous state of what was left on the Annapolis view. How can I make that refresh each time?  Also, the zoom isn't clear with your version to covert over to mine.  Thank you for your help!